# Magento - Products which dont belong to a particular category displayed under it

Tags: magento, categories, product

I have 2 subcategories under MEN category in store i.e

- MEN

  - JEANS & TROUSERS
  - JUMPERS

When i list the products of the store which belong to JEANS & TROUSERS
i see some products are picked from category JUMPERS
I check their configuration in admin but products are assigned to their respective 
categories..

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Go to the menu *System > Configuration > Index Management* and rebuild the product index.

Comment: Thanx for response but i'm using magento1.3.2.4 and there is no index managment under configuration

Comment: In that case it's in Cache Management and is called catalog index. Since the cause is unknown try rebuilding and clearing everything on that page.